# Python - delete tables from docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

I have a docx file that I need to extract all of the text from. The docx also has tables which I want to disregard/delete.

My current code is:

```
import docx2txt
from docx.api import Document
import docx

#initialize the new columns
ctext = list(textdb['txt'])
ctable = list(textdb['tables'])

#call in the file
x = <docx_filepath>
document = Document(x)
tables = document.tables

#see the actual text of tables
for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print (cell.text)

#tells the count of how many tables are in the docx
tablelength = str(len(tables))
ctable.append(tablelength.replace("'",""))

#process the actual text (this includes the table text right now)
text2 = docx2txt.process(x)
ctext.append(text2.replace("'",""))        

#write values back to the list
textdb['txt'] = ctext
textdb['tables'] = ctable
```

I want all of the table text out of the file. Right now each table will show up as an individual element within python (EX:  docx.table.Table at 0x1d303c4f2b0)

Any help would be great - thanks,

Comment: Please don't answer in the question itself. If you've solved your own question, there's nothing wrong with posting the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#copy the iter_block_items function from https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/276
from os import scandir
totaltext= []
for filename in scandir(directory):
    sentences = []
    x = filename.path
    cable = Document(x)
    for item in iter_block_items(cable):
        sentences.append(item.text if isinstance(item, Paragraph) else '<table>') 
totaltext.append(sentences)
```

You can then just run a script to delete all instances of "< table >" using re.sub